# What is the best way to web-scrape facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, web-scraping

I am attempting to create a way to look up a contact of someone using Facebook, however the url which I would use "https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=9*********" will only work if you are logged into a Facebook account, does Facebook give any APIs to allow something similar to this, I am writing this in swift on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to web-scrape Facebook, for the following reasons:

- Screen-scraping is a tedious and fragile last resort, used in legacy systems, like main-frame banking software. Facebook provide an SDK for various platforms, [including iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) that provides access to Facebook data.
- Facebook (and other social networks) allow [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authentication. This is safer, as the client (ie iOS application) never sees the username/password credentials that were used to authenticate. Instead authentication is done via a web-view and the device is issued an access token. If the device is ever lost this token can be revoked.

Try running some of the iOS sample applications provided by Facebook.

Comment: Plus, scraping without explicit prior written consent by Facebook is against their ToS.